# OpenSL ES can not play audio on Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-ndk, pcm, opensl

I decode amrnb to PCM, then put right pcm buffer to Enqueue buffer (I'm sure PCM data is right), but no sound is heard. And when feeding buffer, log outputs:

```
/AudioTrack(14857): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?)
```

My code is below, and my questions are:

1. Is there something wrong when I use the OpenSL ES?
2. Is it true that OpenSL ES only works on the real device?

Sample code:

```
void AudioTest()
{    

    StartAudioPlay();

    while(1)
    {
          //decode AMR to PCM

      /* Convert to little endian and write to wav */

          //write buffer to buffer queue     
      AudioBufferWrite(littleendian, 320);

   }
}

void bqPlayerCallback(SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf bq, void *context)
{

//do nothing

}

void AudioBufferWrite(const void* buffer, int size) 
{

    (*gBQBufferQueue)->Enqueue(gBQBufferQueue, buffer, size );

}

// create buffer queue audio player
void SlesCreateBQPlayer(/*AudioCallBackSL funCallback, void *soundMix,*/ int rate, int nChannel, int bitsPerSample ) 
{

    SLresult result;

    // configure audio source
    SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue loc_bufq = {SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, 2};

    SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, 1, SL_SAMPLINGRATE_8,
        SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
        SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER, SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN};

    SLDataSource audioSrc = {&loc_bufq, &format_pcm};

    // configure audio sink
    SLDataLocator_OutputMix loc_outmix = {SL_DATALOCATOR_OUTPUTMIX, gOutputMixObject};
    SLDataSink audioSnk = {&loc_outmix, NULL};

    // create audio player
    const SLInterfaceID ids[3] = {SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE, SL_IID_EFFECTSEND, SL_IID_VOLUME};
    const SLboolean req[3] = {SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE};
    result = (*gEngineEngine)->CreateAudioPlayer(gEngineEngine, &gBQObject, &audioSrc, &audioSnk,
            3, ids, req);

    // realize the player
    result = (*gBQObject)->Realize(gBQObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);

    // get the play interface
    result = (*gBQObject)->GetInterface(gBQObject, SL_IID_PLAY, &gBQPlay);

    // get the buffer queue interface
    result = (*gBQObject)->GetInterface(gBQObject, SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE,
            &gBQBufferQueue);

    // register callback on the buffer queue
    result = (*gBQBufferQueue)->RegisterCallback(gBQBufferQueue, bqPlayerCallback, NULL/*soundMix*/);

    // get the effect send interface
    result = (*gBQObject)->GetInterface(gBQObject, SL_IID_EFFECTSEND,
            &gBQEffectSend); 

    // set the player's state to playing
    result = (*gBQPlay)->SetPlayState(gBQPlay, SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think you're correct in that the emulator's OpenSL ES support doesn't actually work.  I've never gotten it to work in practice, while it works on any device I've tried.

In my application I have to support Android 2.2 as well, so I have a fallback to use JNI to access the Java AudioTrack APIs.  I added a special case to my app to always use the AudioTrack interface when the emulator is detected.